# Assigning a Bootstrap Popover to <textarea id="some_id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I have a Rails app with a form. The form has a text-area like this:

```
<div class="controls">
  <textarea class="text-field" name="some_model[some_attribute]" rows="5" id="some_id"></textarea>
</div>
```

Somewhere on the page there is a div id like this:

```
<div id="preview"></div>
```

I want the user to see a preview of his input, with input html interpreted. Therefore I have a Coffeescript that does the following:

```
$ ->
  $("#some_id").keyup (event) ->

    preview = $("#preview")

    if event.currentTarget.value.length > 0
      preview.children().remove()
      prevContatiner = $("<a />")
      prevContatiner.attr "href", "#"
      prevContatiner.attr "rel", "tooltip"
      prevContatiner.attr "title", "HTML output"
      prevContatiner.attr "data-animation", false
      prevContatiner.attr "data-html", true
      prevContatiner.attr "data-placement", "top"
      prevContatiner.attr "data-content", event.currentTarget.value
      prevContatiner.attr "id", "preview-text"

      preview.append(prevContatiner)

      showMe = $("#preview-text").popover()
      showMe.popover('show')
    else
      preview.children().remove()
```

This works just fine, so now a nice little preview popover appears. However, I want to move the preview popover so it appears right above the text box. And here come my challenge:

If I replace this line:

```
    preview = $("#preview")
```

with this line:

```
    preview = $("#some_id")
```

then the popover doesn't work anymore.

Could anyone tell me what I have missed? Is a text-area not a valid div that can be assigned popovers to?

Comment: Does this id exists in your document "#some_id"?

Comment: You mean if **id="some_id"** exists in my html (view file)? It does. It is the id that the keyup functionality has been assigned to.

Comment: I see. Try using preppend instead of append. preview.preppend(prevContatiner)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. when I replace **append** with **prepend** in the original working version it does the same trick, however it dosen't when I replace **preview = $("#preview")** with **preview = $("#some_id")**. It seems like it behaves exactly like **append**